# Display a button in gridview

Tags: asp.net, database, button, gridview

I have a grid view which display records by reading the data from a local database. I want to display a button called view with each record displayed. Simply meaning in each row there should be an asp.net button called view Details.

Here is my grid view code:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="ItemView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="list" DataKeyNames="ItemID" 
        DataSourceID="ADDataSource" GridLines="Both" Width="215px">
        <Columns>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="itemID" HeaderText="Item ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Item Name" HeaderText="Item Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Item Brand" HeaderText="Item Brand" />

            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />


     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

I have added a button to delete records and edit records through common field property, but how do i add my own button called view to display in each row as the other 2 buttons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I managed do it myself.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="topic" HeaderText="Topic Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Vehicle Brand" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Model" HeaderText="Vehicle Model" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Vehicle Year" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Button ID="viewDetails" runat="server" Text="View" />

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```